# Overlap when Passing data to View Component and View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC CORE Project,

I have View Component in the Layout page and pass string type data to it,

and i have View that i pass data of type integer to it,

the problem when run that error appear:

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Int', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.String'.
```

Comment: `return View(yourInteger.ToString())`

Comment: Can you include the source code for us to review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem because i was pass my model as string to the view component,
and the view take it as view name not model
i put my string in class and pass it as model class and it work with me
thanks any one try to help me